# Android : Starting a Service from an Intent service

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have got the  Activity Recognition Intent Service form the Location API running in my app. I would like to start a service when the user activity changes. But I cant seem to get it work. Here is what I have tried:

In the Intent Service class for the activity recognition intent service: (Edit: Added a log to the if condition.)

```
 @Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
 {
        // Get the update
        ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);

        // Get the most probable activity from the list of activities in the update
        DetectedActivity mostProbableActivity = result.getMostProbableActivity();

        // Get the type of activity
        int currentActivity = mostProbableActivity.getType();      

        if(currentActivity == DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
        {
            Log.w("Rakshak", "in the if condition"); <-- this gets posted.
            sendNotification(); // this just send a notification that the service has started. 
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            intent.setAction("start");
            startService(i);   <-- this dose'nt start the service. 

        }
}
```

In the Manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />

 <application
     ....

     <service android:name="driver.rakshak.drivetrackeradmin.MyService"/>    

    <service android:name="driver.rakshak.drivetrackeradmin.ActivityRecognitionIntentService"/>  
 </application>
```

I have got a button that the user can click to manually start the service and that works fine. It is only here when I would like the service to start automatically it doesn't work.

The app doesn't crash so I don't have any errors form the log to post.

Let me know if you need to see any more of the code.

Cheers.

Comment: what is the value of your currentActivity variable ?

Comment: it gets set in the line about the "if statement". I know the "if code" gets called because the notification gets sent.

Comment: Could you please share your AndroidManifest? Also, do you need to set this action "start"?

Comment: I have added (what I think are) the relevant bits from the Android manifest file. I have registered the service and have the necessary permission. Let me know if you need to see any more of the manifest. As for the setAction("start"), no I think I can get it work with out it. But if I can have it in I would like to.

Comment: Try to add a intent-filter into your Service for the action "start".

Comment: Did not work. :( . I have a button in the app UI that lets the user start this service manually and that works perfectly fine. It is only here in the Intent service where I want to start the service automatically that it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Context of the IntentService is destroyed after onHandleIntent returns, the Intent created by

> Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);

isn't valid anymore.

Try creating your Intent via getApplicationContext()

> Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);

This might solve this issue.